# Can we make "grav lifts"?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, physics

So in many sci-fi franchises, there are these things called "grav-lifts" that supposedly cancel the pull of gravity of whatever they are placed on the bottom of.

So is this possible?

I understand that we don't have gravity manipulating devices, but in theory, would such a device be possible?

If not, is there a way to mimic this effect? And I don't mean hovercraft such as we have today with an air cushion. I mean actually being able to hover or lift-off with a similar device.

---

**Edit:** I seem to be getting a lot of elevator-related answers. I am not asking for levitation for the use of something like an elevator, I am asking it in the context of a hovering/flying **vehicle**

Comment: even if it was possible: going up would be like falling with your head first. extremely uncomfortable.

Comment: @ths Not if it applied to all parts of your body equally. If we're making stuff up, why not?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I think ths meant that if you were reversing gravity, it would feel like falling headfirst, rather than being lifted.

Comment: I'm kind of confused about what's being described here. It sounds like the gravity-proof material in H. G. Wells' *the First Men in the Moon*, but I don't remember seeing anything like that in any other science fiction franchise. Can you give some examples where it appears?

Comment: Or do you just mean a platform that's able to hover without any visible means of support, such that you could stand on top of it? That's quite a different thing from cancelling the pull of gravity, but it's certainly quite common in SF. It would help to clarify.

Comment: @Nathaniel : in that case it wouldn't be any kind of "canceling the pull of gravity", it would just be a platform levitated probably by electromagnetic means. That's possible with today's technology. Probably they don't build them because of the costs involved, and safety concerns. But maglev trains exist, powerful electromagnets exist, so a platform raised by a series of circular electromagnets around it in a tube would be feasible. However, likely the fixed electromagnets would envelop it completely, so it would feel claustrophobic. And in case of a power failure you'd plummet down to death.

Comment: @ths: Pretty sure the idea here is that the _platform_ has inverted gravity, and its load does not, but the platform has more mass than its cargo and thus "wins" in the gravitational tug of war. Secondly, even if the cargo would also have inverted gravity, when you're in freefall the orientation of your head does not matter because freefall _feels like_ microgravity to the object that is in freefall.

Comment: @Nathaniel something like this exists in Star Wars, except they are called repulserlifts but they give levitation like what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy answer: **<s>No.</s> *Maybe.***

More complicated answer...

If you ignore the word "grav" and look for any way to create levitation, it's hypothetically possible to create a magnetic field aligned to oppose the Earth's magnetic field to levitate an object. We see this the basic form of this effect already with superconductors. (Image courtesy the [Royal Society of Chemistry](https://edu.rsc.org/feature/100-years-of-superconductivity/3007335.article).)

[image]

However, today we can only do this using another magnet as the base reference for the levitation. In other words, while the science has the *potential* to lead to "anti-gravity" (or simply "levitation"), we can not in any way do it today.

The problem, which is well explained [here](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/QA/listing.php?id=1027&t=magnets-floating-in-the-earths-field) is that the Earth's magnetic field is so large and so spread out that it is both weak and uniform at any point on or above the Earth's surface. This means that you need an enormously intense magnetic field, even using superconductors, to levitate. And with technology today, that's flat out impossible simply because we have no way to lift the weight of the energy-providing device along with the Clarkean magnetic emitters.

And that's the core problem of why, knowing today's technology, the only valuable answer is "**<s>no</s> *Maybe***." Thanks to various laws (like the really inconvenient laws of thermodynamics), we can't (perhaps, yet) see a way to produce that much power with a device that's so light that there's lifting capacity to *add a burden.*

**But...**

While the answer is that it's impossible today to do it, it isn't implausible such that it couldn't be used in a story. We have nuclear reactors that drive mighty aircraft carriers through the buoyant medium of salt water. The fact that we can build energy-creating systems that can propel objects much heavier than themselves implies that we just need to find the right combination of materials to do it for the sake of levitation.

**Having said that...**

The astute observer would quickly notice that I'm talking about levitation on a planet. Levitation on a space ship could be much, much simpler thanks to the need to bring the repulsive force with you. A plate on the floor that generates a strong magnetic field that the plate you stand on pushes against. It would be a neat trick to keep them aligned with any stability... but that's not beyond the possibilities of reason.

But the ability to walk around with a single plate and levitate anywhere on a planet or in space?

<s>No.</s> *Maybe.*

---

**Edit:** @ChrisH linked a great article that changes my "no" to "maybe."

- [Diamagnetic Levitation](https://www.ru.nl/hfml/research/levitation/diamagnetic-levitation/), an article from the High Field Magnet Laboratory of Radboud University.

Which, among other things, demonstrates the levitation of a live frog. Frog... Human... it's just a matter of scale, right?

Comment: " a magnetic field inverse to the Earth's magnetic field"  that's surely a typo, JBH?  You mean inverse to Earth's gravity, right?  (the Earth's magnetic field is tiny and has nothing to do with anything about raising objects with magnets.)

Comment: @Fattie, My answer is about magnetism, not gravity. It's poorly worded, but anti-gravity only comes (insofar as Humanity can understand) from negative mass. It would have been more accurate to say "a magnetic field aligned against the Earth's magnetic field." The only experiments levitating against the Earth's magnetic field (diamagnetics) have been successful only when the poles are reversed. However, you're not correct when you say "nothing to do...." It's possible, just not practical in any way, shape, or form. Please remember the context of the OP's question.

Comment: hi @JBH !  you may misunderstand me.  The Earth's magnetic field is parallel to the surface of the Earth (and indeed, heading roughly towards the North pole).  In your room, say, the (absolutely tiny) "Earth's magnetic field" will be directed from your sofa towards (say) your TV, horizontal, along the floor, parallel to the surface of the Earth.  "inverse to the Earth's magnetic field" would just be from the TV to the sofa.  Maglev trains, etc, or the photo in your answer, have (incredibly powerful) magnets which push UP towards the ceiling.

Comment: the tiny magnetic field of the Earth (towards the TV) is totally unrelated to maglev pointing upwards.  maglev trains or the maglev object in the blue photo, work completely identically at any point on Earth, or, on other planets with no magnetic field, or if the Earth happened to have no magnetic field.

Comment: @Fattie I didn't mention maglev trains in my answer. You're welcome to read through the link I provided... or take a college class. The existence of any magnetic field presents the possibility of a repulsive counterpart. It's a matter of energy, which I point out would be impossible at this time.

Comment: hi @JBH , hmm, if you have basic training in Vectors and some physics, you'd see that it looks like you may have made a typo you just haven't noticed. Notice your sentence "possible to create a magnetic field inverse to the Earth's magnetic field to levitate an object" - such as in the blue photo. In the blue photo, the direction of force of the mag. field levitating the puck is pointing *upwards*; the direction of force of the Earth's mag. field in that photo is *sideways* (and it has no relation, at all, to the experiment.) You could ask on the Physics SE site for clarification.

Comment: @Fattie You misunderstand magnetism. Magnetism is described mathematically using force vectors, but what actually exists are flux lines. Repulsion and attraction occur based on whether or not the flux lines of the two magnets are moving with or against one another. The reason repulsion or attraction is stronger at poles is due to the higher density of flux lines, nothing more. The magnet in the photo is stronger per-cubic-unit-of-space than Earth's magnetic field, but there's no other difference. You're welcome to find out more at [physics.se] yourself.

Comment: @JBH If you want to levitate something, you're fighting gravity, not earth's magnetic field—which is Fattie's point.

Comment: @Sean And that was L.Dutch's answer. As the OP says, "Is there a way to mimic this effect?" Magnetic levitation is one such way. If fattie's complaint really is, "this should only be about gravity," then he didn't read the OP's question very well.

Comment: @JBH That's not what Fattie is saying. Please read their original comment in the context of my previous one.

Comment: @Sean OK, I re-read it. It somewhat confirms that fattie is only focusing on gravity, which I addressed in my follow-up comment. I'm not sure fattie needs defending. It seems apparent that he's confused about at least two things. BTW, you have a reputation of only 101 and have only taken the tour. You're awfully involved for someone who's done nothing else on this Stack. Please confirm that you're not a second account belonging to fattie.

Comment: @JBH Magnetic levitation fights the effect of gravity to keep an object suspended. Your answer seems to erroneously imply that magnetic levitation fights the effect of the earth's magnetism to keep an object suspended. Fattie was asking if that was a typo.

Comment: **Dia**magnetic levitation [was used by Nobel winner Andre Geim, see first reference in link](https://www.ru.nl/hfml/research/levitation/diamagnetic-levitation/) to levitate a live frog.  Scaling up to humans (and enough height) is only probably impossible

Comment: @Sean Thanks. I appreciate knowing.

Comment: @ChrisH That's a great article! Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 6):

In Newton formulation of gravity $F=G$${m_1 \cdot m_2}\over r^2$.

The general relativity formulation is a tad more complex, but it also states that a mass bends space time, and than bending causes what we see as gravity.

In both formulations the only way to make gravity a repulsive force would be to have a negative mass. A negative mass would be such that if you pushed it with your finger it would move toward your finger, not away from it.

Needless to say, at the moment we have nothing closer to that. So those devices are purely fictional.

Comment: We do have negative energy, though, with the Casimir effect.

Comment: @nick012000 Keep in mind L.Dutch is only talking about the force of gravity. Also keep in mind that the Casimir Effect is quantum and as yet has no application in the macro world. And if I understand it correctly, it doesn't express negative energy, that's just a mathematical convention to distinguish between attractive and repulsive force. Magnets don't have negative energy, either, but they do have attractive and repulsive forces that can be mathematically expressed as negative values.

Comment: That isn't quite correct. In general relativity you can create a small region with a repulsive force by taking a torus-shaped matter distribution and accelerate its spin around the circular torus axis (the way a smoke ring turns). There will be a "repulsive force" in that small region - though the object as a whole still attracts of course: https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.1969340

Answer (score 4):

## If They're Stationary, Probably

As has been pointed out by other responders, negating gravity is hard or impossible.  Maglev, as suggested by @JBH, is an approach.  But, assuming that your "grav lift" is an architectural feature like an elevator, then there is another potential approach:

## Acoustic Levitation

So, recent developments in acoustic levitation use [acoustic vortices](https://www.zmescience.com/science/news-science/acoustic-tractor-beam-042342/) to suspend objects larger than the wavelength of the sound.  It can be ultrasonic, and therefore not (directly) dangerous to human hearing, but at the moment the best that can be managed is a 2cm polystyrene ball.

To levitate bigger, more massive things (humans, say) would require both better control over the vortices and a *lot* more acoustic power, but those are engineering challenges, rather than a matter of overcoming physical laws.

Now, this wouldn't be practical for something that was less elevator-like, you're not going to get a [landspeeder](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Landspeeder) from this, because the emitters have to surround the levitated object (at least in one plane), but if you absolutely, positively have to move a human (or similar masses) through the air from one place to another without putting them in a small mobile room, this is probably your best bet.

(It is, however, *enormously* less energy-efficient then lowering a small room attached to a cable, and then hoisting it back up again.)

---

I am including a link to [a video demonstration](https://youtu.be/nFJpEsKATXE) under the fold, because the link might eventually go bad, but it is supremely cool to watch.

Comment: "negating gravity is hard or impossible"  quite a statement  :)

Comment: @Fattie Why do you think JD's statement to be unusual? Considering the expenditure of energy and effort just to put a satellite in orbit, he's absolutely correct. An illogical observation may suggest that a child's simple jump "negates gravity," but that's a false assumption because the child doesn't stay there. An airplane or a hot air balloon would be good examples of less expensive levitation, but those are outside the context of the OP's question. He/she wants anti-grav, not flight.

Comment: +1, I hadn't thought about acoustical levitation. Great idea!

Comment: @JBH - the "hard" part is funny.  one can simply type "negating gravity is impossible"

Comment: @Fattie Except that you'd be wrong. We negate gravity every time we launch an object beyond Earth's gravity well. Perhaps part of the problem is that you're confusing the OP's intent (to lift something against the force of gravity but not mechanically) with actually changing the effect of gravity, e.g. to stand on but underneath the plate because the plate is creating an attractive gravity that is greater than and contrary to planetary gravity. I'd need Firestryke to clarify, but I don't believe that's what he/she is asking.

Comment: Well, the headline question is "can we make grav lifts," and the second paragraph states the question clearly.  Later, the OP asks "**If not**, is there a way to mimic this effect?"

Comment: Acoustic levitation **is** dangerous to humans! To lift such a mass, the air friction would provide enough heat to burn or vaporize the human.

Oh.

Vaporize. Burn.

Yep, human goes up, just arrives...in a somewhat different shape.

Comment: @Klaws - citation?  Nothing in the papers on using acoustic vortices (rather than the more traditional standing waves) suggested that there were major heat losses - that was one of the advantages of the new technique, because it meant that temperature sensitive items like pharmaceuticals could be manipulated using it.

Comment: @jdunlop I got this from Tom Danley, like, 25 years ago, about some experiments for NASA. Let me see...Google found me that: "Tom Danley's acoustic levitator from back in the 1980's would start levitating light objects at about 155dB, it worked at about 22KHz and could light a cigarette with acoustic friction at about 175 dB."

Comment: @Klaws - you may want to read the linked papers from the article in my answer.  Acoustic vortices avoid that issue, because they're not dependent on standing waves to move the object.  New technology! :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, some time ago there seemed to be an accidental discovery of a "gravity shielding" effect in an experiment by Eugene Podkletnov at the university of Tampere in Finland. Created a lot of buzz for a short period and then died, so it was probably nothing, but I have come across arguments why it might be possible according to the known laws of physics.

I believe it involved a spinning magnetic field in a superconductor, reducing the effect of gravity on all objects above it by some small percentage.

Some random links that might help you on your way:
https://electrogravityphysics.com/gravity-shielding-finland/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugene_Podkletnov

Answer (score 0):

No, not in the way these "grav lifts/antigrav lifts" are ***depicted in the literature***.

**Surprisingly, this has nothing to do with (anti-)gravity.**

A typical scenario would be: you return from lunch, enter the mgea-skyscraper at ground level, step into an "antigrav tube" and move up to your office on the 240th floor, where you and your lunch arrive, quite possibly, separately.

The idea of this kind of life was perhaps inspired by a paternoster lift (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paternoster_lift), and movement in the lift tube is usually described just like that of paternoster lift, just without cabins.

Now, with constant and human-manageable velocity (the passenger enters and exits the lift on his/her own, by means of a handle), this trip will take some time (let's say 15 minutes for single 240 floor trip). Basically, when you arrive at ground level, you can immediate embark on the return trip to your office because the travel time leaves no time for lunch. Which saves you from the embarrassing situation of you and your lunch arriving separately.

Obviously, one "solution" would be to have constant acceleration (and deceleration) in the grav lift. So, on the trip from your 240th floor office to ground level, you would accelerate for the first half the trip and decelerate for the second half. Mathematically, with about 1 g-force of acceleration, you could expect to arrive in maybe 20 seconds. Practically, you will crash into Guido from the 120th floor after 10 seconds, at a speed of 350km/h. Lunch separation issues are now the least of your worries.

Again, this is about how the lifts are ***depicted in the science fiction literature***. You might add accelerator tubes which bring the passenger up to some fixed travel speed before entering the main tube, and some clever exit system which pulls the passenger out of the main tube upon arrival at the pre-selected destination and slows them down in a separate  decelerator tube. But that's far from being as "elegantly simple" as the grav lifts depicted in the literature.

Another solution would be to "bundle" passenger with similar trips (this is actually done in real life right now, to increase the bandwidth of conventional lifts). You might even provide cabins for these "passenger bundles" (groups).

Oh, wait. That's too much like a boring ordinary lift. Note that in very tall building, even the boring ordinary lift already accelerate (and decelerate) at 0.5 g-force - and this is already a bit of a lunch containment issue for some people.

Comment: But having an ~1g acceleration (calibrated to whatever planet you're on) is so convenient. You step in at the bottom and it accelerates you for the first half of your trip and then you simply continue on your trajectory upwards for the second half until you arrive at your destination at a perfect standstill (do be quick about grabbing the hand hold for the exit, because you won't be there long). On the way down you just jump and halfway down the 1g deceleration catches you. Having a different from average air resistance/surface area may result in not reaching your destination...in one piece.

Answer (score 0):

### Bonus Answer: Directional Gravity

One issue with gravity is that it's omnidirectional. So if you can generate artificial gravity to lift an object away from the surface of the Earth (meaning 1 g-force of gravity), it would also affect everything else in the vicinity. And that's vicinity on a planetary scale. Basically, it would appear that you just created an Earth-size gravity source, in additional to the already present Earth itself. That sucks. Literally.

The obvious solution is directional gravity (often called a "tractor beam" in the science fiction literature). To provide useful directivity to radiation (radiation like electric fields, or sound emitted/radiated from a speaker), the wavelength of the radiation must be  significantly smaller than the dimension of the emitter. Obviously, with higher frequency we have smaller wavelengths, so higher frequencies will work better (like in audio, where higher bass is "hard to direct" and the treble is "hard to get omnidirectional").

We know that gravity waves exist. if we could generate gravity waves with device whose dimension is significantly that the wavelength of our (high-frequency) gravity waves, we could end up with directional gravity waves. That won't be perfect (just look up "antenna directivity" in Google), but it's clearly an improvement over good old omnidirectional gravity.

Now, gravity waves don't help us very much, I guess. If they act like radio or sound waves, they do not move stuff around but cause stuff to vibrate around some position.

All credit goes to **jdunlop** for mentioning Acoustic Levitation. I currently cannot rule out that **gravitational vortices** can be generated, just like the acoustic vortices mentioned by jdunlop - and that these could be used as some kind of "tractor beam".

Answer (score -1):

There's a simple way to solve this: Superconductors. A superconductor is a material that's been chilled to the point where there's little, if any, electrical resistance, and running an electric current through a superconductor produces a powerful magnet. That magnet can be used to provide enough force to negate the weight of an object.